# Weird linear regression learning curve

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to build a prediction model for apartments price. I use python scikit-learn toolset. I'm using a dataset having total floor area and location of the apartment, which I have converted to dummy features. So the dataset looks like this:
[image]
Then I build a learning curve to see how the model is doing. 
I build the learning curve this way:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve

model = LinearRegression()
training_sizes, training_scores, validation_scores = learning_curve(
    estimator = model,
    X = X_train,
    y = y_train,
    train_sizes = np.linspace(5, len(X_train) * 0.8, dtype = int), 
    cv = 5
)
line1, line2 = plt.plot(
    training_sizes, training_scores.mean(axis = 1), 'g', 
    training_sizes, validation_scores.mean(axis = 1), 'r')
plt.legend((line1, line2), ('Training', 'Cross-validation'))
```

The picture I see is somewhat confusing:
[image: Learning curve on training and cross-validation sets]
Anomalies I see here are:

1. Huge error on cross-validation set
2. Error not steadily decreasing on training examples number growth.

Is it normal?

Learning curve of training set only is also not so smooth but at least the error isn't that huge:
[image: Learning curve on training set]

Also I tried to add to add polynomial features of 2nd degree. But this didn't make the model perform any different. And because I have a lot of categorical features (total 106) it takes quite long even for 2nd degree polynomial. So I didn't try for higher degrees.

Also I tried to build a model using as simple cost function and gradient descent as possible using Octave. The result with weird error was same.

Update:
Thanks to [tolik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60734720/200160) I made several amendments:

**Data preparation:**
Categorical data are independent. So I can't combine them into one feature.
Features were scaled using StandardScaler(). Thank you for that.

**Feature extraction:**
After features transformation with PCA I found out one new feature has explained variance ratio over 99%. Though it's strange I used only this one. That also allowed to increase polynomial degree though it didn't increase performance.

**Model selection:**
I tried several different models but none seem to perform better than LinearRegression. Interesting thing - all models perform worse on full data set. Probably it's because I sorted by price and higher prices are rather outliers. So when I start training sets on 1000 samples and go to the maximum, I get this picture (for nearly all models):
[image]

Comment: What language or program are you using? I recommend editing your question to add the corresponding tag.

Comment: I guess you should add the code of `learning_curve` as well.

Comment: The error you get it weirdly huge (10^21) and negative. Maybe there's something wrong with your cost function inside `learning_curve`. What do you get if you only plot the error for the training data?

Comment: I believe the cost function is squared mean error but made negative for cross-validation set in order to make graph more visually appealing.

Comment: One guess: when you convert locations to dummies, you likely need to drop one location dummy from the regression. Otherwise, the dummy matrix + the constant column (intercept) will be singular. In practice, this leads to numerical instability and likely huge coefficients. When applied out of sample, this may account for the surprising error term.

Comment: To add to the above, you could run OLS in a single batch with [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html) with `hasconst=False` and check if you get any warnings related to singularity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My explanation have 3 steps: The data preparation, feature extraction, and model selection.

**Data preparation:**

- In this dataset there are lots of Categorical and Ordinal values. If
  the column has several non related categories it's ok to one-hot it.
  but if the column has categories with order like
  "bad","normal","good" you can convert it to numerical as
  {Good:1,Normal:0.5,Bad:0}.
- Value ranges: the value ranges for each feature differs from the other, therefore the best thing to do is to normalise each feature along itself between 0:1.

**Feature Extraction:**

- Your goal is to maximise the score so I guess you don't care about which feature is more important. Use **PCA** (has an implementation in scikit-learn library) , this algorithm convert your feature vectors into different features that each of them is a linear combination of the other features.  These new features are ordered by their explained variance. The first features describes the data better than the last one. You select the first features that their `explained_variance_` sums to 99%. Now you have weigh less features.

**Model Selection:** 
You don't really know what is a good model, because **No Free Lunch Theory** but in this problem the best results that don't use deep learning , use these: XGBoost-Regressor , Random-Forest-Regressor ,Ada-Boost.

**The most important thing is the Data Preparation!!!**

Comment: May be just additional question. First I scale features in training set and then do PCA on them and choose first x transformed features to train a model. How then I predict a target variable on single data sample? I have again first to scale features from this sample and to PCA transformation?

Comment: you should transform the test data according to the fitted PCA object. First you ```fit_transform()``` the PCA on train and remove the least important vectors, then you ```transform()``` the PCA  on the test and remove the same vectors. now you can predict on your test.

Comment: Yeah. It's just that first I train a model and dump it to the file to be used later. And datasets to predict are loaded in different stream and come mostly one by one. So would the proper approach be to train a model each time before running a prediction?

Comment: you can pickle the fitted PCA transformer , and also write to file (or remember somehow) the number of features you used to fit the model. To predict you have to load the pickled pca, ```transform()``` the test and slice the number of features you need for model prediction.